# Was it really necessary to retrieve the sword of Gryffindor under conditions of need valor?

Tags: harry-potter, gryffindor

We know that the sword will only appear for true Gryffindors. But once it is there, couldn't it be used by everyone?
Snape was able to hold and carry the sword to the Forest (and if he can hold it, he can use it). So why must Harry take it under conditions of need and valor? Snape could just have placed it before their tent for example, they would find it and be able to use it.
The sword does not serve people as the elder wand does, if it is already there, lying in the floor, is it really necessary to do something brave in order to get it?

Comment: You could argue that Snape was acting under conditions of need and valor.

Comment: @mcgyver5 You could, but that doesn't answer the question why the conditions are necessary. Especially as Harry had already proven himself to be worthy of the sword.

Comment: It magically showing up likely requires courage and valor. Picking it up while it is lying around in Dumbledore’s office not so much...

Answer (score 3):

Comment from Jon Custer about magically showing up vs picking it up from the trash seems to be the critical point here.

What was important was that Harry and the gang **believed** that the sword came here magicaly.

If the sword appears in the situation needing valor. It means that the sword choose to be here.
So it's ok in this instance to find this ultra precious artefact lying around.
It's magic, so it's ok !

On the other hand, if that the sword pop up in front of the tent. It mean that someone put it there. So they will investigate, and they will distrust it.